# SPA calling a NET Core Rest API to external Authenticantion (OAuth)

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, oauth

I have

```
www.mydomain.com -> SPA app
```

and

```
www.mydomain.com/api -> NET core Rest Api
```

Both are hosted on separated IIs Applications, and I added a web.config on my Vuejs app to allow my setup to work :

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Handle History Mode and custom 404/500" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{HTTP_URL}" pattern="^/api/(.+)" negate="true" /> 
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

All working fine until I implemented a custom OAuth provider on my Net Core app like that one : https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/tree/dev/src/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Apple

So I configured my CallbackPath to  "/start", so it should generate:

```
redirect_uri=www.mydomain.com/start
```

but it generate

```
redirect_uri=www.mydomain.com/api/start
```

I know why its happening, but I dont know how can I force redirect_uri to not use /api

Is it possible to change that? Or should I try to host both APP on same IIS application?

Thanks